# How can God be three persons?

Tags: trinity, persons-of-the-trinity

How can God be three Persons when He is defined by thousands of singular personal pronouns, which define ONE Person?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How it is possible to be one God in three persons (Jesus, Holy Ghost, and God the Father)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/66588/how-it-is-possible-to-be-one-god-in-three-persons-jesus-holy-ghost-and-god-th)

Comment: Or this [question:What is the biblical basis for the doctrine of trinity consisting of three persons](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/57432/22319)

Comment: This question was dealt with, extensively, at the inception of the website nine years ago.

Comment: A [similar](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/78954) question has been asked recently, leading to [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112286) chat exchange.

Comment: As a technical side note, please ask moderators to [merge](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your [two](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/4934) distinct [accounts](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/50682), and be careful to prevent the accidental creation of multiple accounts on [other](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/16746) related sites.

Comment: In Eastern Orthodoxy, God is one and he is the Father. But God is not alone. He has with him the Son and the Holy Spirit who are of the same nature with him. In this case, there is really no problem why the one God is referred to with singular pronouns because the one God refers to the person of the Father alone.

Comment: When God is referred to by thousands of singular personal pronouns, it is correct that it defines one person. Logically, singular personal pronouns refer to one person only. Now this one God being called a "he" a thousand times in the Bible is the one person of the Father. But the Father alone is not the only divine person who exists. There exist two other divine persons in the New Testament (the Son and the Holy Spirit). The Trinity or the three divine selves (identified with singular personal pronouns "I", "he") are of the same nature.

Comment: The question seems to presuppose that reality (in this case the nature of God) should conform to our use of language (in this case pronouns). I'm suspicious about that presupposition. External reality is not bound by our language. Language ought to conform itself to reality, and in most circumstances it does that reasonably well --- but not when the reality is (like the divine nature) far beyond our understanding. Language then expresses reality as best it can, but that might be a very poor expression and fall far short of the reality.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not existential but definitional. God exists and is a certain way. We can define "person" to exclude God's Trinitarian nature as a logical possibility, or we can define "person" to include both human persons and the three Divine persons. The Church has chosen to base the definition of person on God and humanity, not on humanity alone. It recognizes multiple aspects of personality as already understood by human philosophers in the Father, Son and Holy Spirit, where they are shown in Scripture to be distinct persons.

At the same time, there is a unity among the persons of the Trinity that no group of human persons has between them. Our unity as individuals does not extend to incorporate other persons. God's does. That makes God very different from us, in a category by Himself.

The Bible says that when a man and women marry, they become one flesh. This unity is limited but real. Perhaps if Adam and Eve had not eaten from the tree of the knowledge of Good and Evil before consummating their marriage, human marriages, families and even all of humankind would have had such unity as God always has? This insight gives us the answer.

How can God be three persons yet be one God? Because He never sinned. Sin brings division. Division cannot occur unless there was a preexisting unity.

Unity is the original state of being. Our separation from one another not just in personhood but in love, communion and fellowship, that is what needs explanation.

Comment: This only vaguely attempts to answer the question, ignores the specific point about the use of singular pronouns and speculates theologically (veering into territory which would be rejected by many if not most Trinitarian schools of thought)\

Comment: . . . .  and does so without (at the present state of edit) referencing a single text of scripture.